# Google map marker click function issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am building an interactive map with google.  I will have a lot of map markers that when clicked will open a bootstrap modal with content relative to that location.  Is it possible to just have 1 modal call in the script, then load it with the content relative to the marker clicked?  I was thinking I could write a remote html file with all of the different modal contents.  But right now, I have to write a click function for each marker (painstaking), to open a unique modal.

1 modal, 1 click function relative to the marker clicked, unique modal contents loaded depending on marker clicked.  Can this be done?

```
   function initialize() {
  var map;
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 8,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(43.819201,-79.535474),
    disableUi: true
  };
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
      mapOptions);

    var commerciallocations = [
     ['Regan',43.703264,-79.804144],
     ['Lake',43.897239,-78.6594789],
     ['Rowe',43.72277,-80.378554],
     ['Westport',43.649826,-79.6599653],
     ['Vinefresh',42.9556009,-81.6699305]
    ];  

var marker2, i;

for (i = 0; i < commerciallocations.length; i++) {  
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(commerciallocations[i][1], commerciallocations[i][2]),
    map: map,
    icon:'images/commercialmapicon.png'
    });

if (i == [0]){  
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
    $('#modal0').modal();
    });
    }
if (i == [1]){  
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
    $('#modal1').modal();
    });
    }
if (i == [2]){  
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
    $('#modal2').modal();
    });
    }
if (i == [3]){  
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
    $('#modal3').modal();
    });
    }
if (i == [4]){  
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
    $('#modal4').modal();
    });
    }

    };
```

I added the portion of the script I'm having to write in order to tell each marker to open its respective modal.  See how I have to write a click event for each index of the array.  I don't know any other way...

Comment: Actually, seems like you can use a for loop, since each marker has a modal attached to it. Just put them in the correct order and and you will only have to do one modal() call with in the for loop. No?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean.  each marker needs to have a unique content in the modal - thus I have to create modal1,modal2...

Comment: I don't understand why you have so many if statements. Why can't you just do: google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
    $('#modal'+i).modal();
    }); ?

Comment: I'm not very educated in jS/jquery.  I tried what you suggest, I added that to the for loop.  But it doesn't call open the modal.  There aren't errors though.  if I understand correctly, that click function you provided should cycle through the indexes of the array and apply the modal (provided the modals are in order).  It just doesn't launch the modal.

Answer (score 0):

try with put the marker in an array and then in the addListerner function pass the array item and the index  for generate a sequential call to modal like :

```
var arrayForModal = [];
for (i = 0; i < commerciallocations.length; i++) {  
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(commerciallocations[i][1], commerciallocations[i][2]),
map: map,
icon:'images/commercialmapicon.png'
k = arrayForModal.push(marker); 
addListenersOnPolygon(arrayForModal[k-1], 'click', function(k)  { $(('#modal' + (k-1)).modal)});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help guys.  It definitely helped my train of thought, I deconstructed a few other functions I discovered on SO and I managed to write the click function properly.

I added the ID of each Modal into the index of each location in the array (attached the id to the marker).  I then created a variable to identify the index value.  Then I simply called the index with the ID value depending on which marker was clicked within the for loop.

```
    var commerciallocations = [
     ['Regan',43.703264,-79.804144,'#modal0'],
     ['Lake',43.897239,-78.6594789, '#modal1'],
     ['Rowe',43.72277,-80.378554, '#modal2'],
     ['Westport',43.649826,-79.6599653, '#modal3'],
     ['Vinefresh',42.9556009,-81.6699305, '#modal4'],
     ['Winery', 42.1209449,-82.9707676, '#modal5']
    ];


    var markers =[];

    for (var i = 0; i < commerciallocations.length; i++) {  
        var place = commerciallocations[i];
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(commerciallocations[i][1], commerciallocations[i][2]),
        map: map,
        icon:'images/commercialmapicon.png',
        title: place[0],
        popup: place[3]
    });
        markers.push(marker);           

        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
        $(this.popup).modal();
        });
```